# UITableView not displaying correct amount of rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created a table view within a view controller and am trying to set the amount of rows it will have. The amount gets returned from a database and then passed on to the correct method (see below). The problem is that the amount of rows visible is not the same amount that gets returned from the database.

*Within .viewDidLoad()*

```
    self.activeIDs.delegate = self
    self.activeIDs.dataSource = self
    self.activeIDs.rowHeight = 30
    self.activeIDs.reloadData()
```

*Methods that are supposed to "set up" the table view*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = activeIDs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("idCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel!.text = "Test"

        return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var numberOfRows = 0 //Assigning default value
        SQLHandler.getActiveIDAmount {
            amountOfIDs in
            numberOfRows = amountOfIDs.description.toInt()!
            println(numberOfRows) //Displays correct (database) value
        }
    return numberOfRows //Returns correct value EDIT: wrong value.
}
```

Instead of getting the desired amount of rows (4) I always, despite the value which I get from the database, end up with 6? Screenshot of table view in action: http://gyazo.com/753f326177dc8cd6b1734f4d19681d71

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The method you are calling SQLHandler is a completion handler, that means that swift will continue executing your code and just after (and return the numberOfRowns = 0) than after (when the the request finish) it will come back to the block:

```
SQLHandler.getActiveIDAmount {
            amountOfIDs in
            numberOfRows = amountOfIDs.description.toInt()!
            println(numberOfRows) //Displays correct (database) value
            //add the values returned to your dataset here
            //call refresh table and dispatch in the main thread in case
            //this block is running in a background thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
}
```

and print the number of rows.

What you need to do is to call the function `SQLHandler.getActiveIDAmount` somewhere else in your code and `call table.reloadData()` after the callback is finished.

I hope that helps you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. If I were to call SQLHandler.getActiveIDAmount again, would I not have to enter the same information between the {} as before thus not solving the issue? I did some  tests and found out that after the numberOfRows returned was actually 0, its default value. It's probably also worth mentioning that I attempted using this "completion handler" in order to fix the problem where the asynchronous database fetch didn't return the correct value intended for the rows.

Comment: You post in your question "println(numberOfRows) //Displays correct (database) value" so it means your database query is working but you are not using the dataset correctly. You don't have to call the method twice, just once and use the dataSet retrieved to populate the tableView

Comment: But is this not what I am doing? (By the way, I updated my question, since it seems that the value returned was indeed incorrect) I am fetching the amount of rows that I need, just not that the value for numberOfRows (which is returned) is being changed (numberOfRows = amountOfIDs.description.toInt()!)?

Comment: How would I know when the callback is finished?

Comment: @Tice you don't need to know when it finished, you can just call update table from inside it. I update my answer to cover that too.

Comment: What do you mean by "add the values returned to your dataset here"? Isn't this what the "numberOfRows = amountOfIDs..." does? This is what I have so far: http://pastebin.com/MaHCenGG. The dispatch_async method call you added is also causing an infinite loop, causing constant println-output (ex. "Outside callback: 0"). By the way, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Dataset is the set of data you want to display, in your case a good dataset would be an array. So basically what you need to do is to download the data and create an array with this that and use this array to populate your table.

Comment: Is hard for me to help you much more as I don't know what you are trying to do with the pieces of code I am seem, but lets say you are download this data: "1,2,3,4" where each number is a row in the database, you will create an array and append all values, for numberOfRowsInSection you return the number of elements in the array, and for cellForRowAtIndexPath you return the value of the element in the array in the index position. In this example the array is your dataset

Comment: This is what I want to do: I want there to be as many rows in the table view as their is in the database, and for their to be individual data (got from db) populated in each uitableview row . At first, I was not planning on using an array to both set the amount of rows and populate them. I was planning on just - in the numberOfRowsInSection method that we have been discussing - returning the number of rows (an Integer) fetched from the database and then using the method cellForRowAtIndexPath to "just populate" the tableview with my desired data. It seems to hard - all I want is data from async